# How to find the underlying disks of a mirrored volume in LVM (linux)?

Tags: linux, lvm

When I run command `lvs -a` the output shows the logical volumes from which the mirrored-volume has been made but how to find the actual disks from which the sub-logical volume were allocated. Any specific command, options? Or do we have to manually find out?

```
[root@cent06x32vm12 ~]# lvs -a
LV               VG               Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log        Cpy%Sync Convert
mvol3            datavg2          mwi-a-m---  40.00m                         mvol3_mlog   100.00
 [mvol3_mimage_0] datavg2          iwi-aom---  40.00m  <==== How to find which disks these come from
 [mvol3_mimage_1] datavg2          iwi-aom---  40.00m  <====
 [mvol3_mlog]     datavg2          lwi-aom---   4.00m  <====
```

Comment: try with `-o +devices`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show all `lvs` and where they come from you can check with:

```
lvs -ao +devices
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to see the logical extent allocation by physical device is to use:

```
lvdisplay --all --maps
```

If you wish to limit the query to a particular volume group, simply add it as an argument.